# How to get data from firebase after on click on recyclerview like Streaming Apps

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I was trying to make a Music Streaming app. I created an Activity called Display Activity. I make a horizontal  RecyclerView in Display Activity. In my Firebase I created A node name 'ArtistView' which contains Artist List.
After that i load Artist image and Artist name in my Horizontal recyclerView like same as Spotify. There is another node in my firebase which contain songList of Artist. Now my main question is how to make function like when user click "Guri" artist from My RecyclerView then after clicking  it loads list of his Songs in New Activity from Firebase like in Spotify if we click any Artist then it loads songs of Artist in New Activity. Here is the image of my Firebsae Database:-
[Firebase Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGSAh.png)

If you underStand my question then Here is the Code:-

Display Activity:-

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArtistRecyclerView artistRecyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private ValueEventListener eventListener;
    private List<ArtistHoler> artistHolerList;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dispplay);


        artistHolerList = new ArrayList<>();
        artistRecyclerView = new ArtistRecyclerView(this , artistHolerList);


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ArtistView");
        databaseReference.keepSynced(true);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.dispay_recycler_view);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this  , LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL , false);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(artistRecyclerView);

        eventListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    ArtistHoler artistHoler = snapshot.getValue(ArtistHoler.class);
                    artistHolerList.add(artistHoler);

                }

                artistRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }





}
```

Artist Adapter:-

```
public class ArtistRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArtistRecyclerView.HolderOfArtist> {
    private List<ArtistHoler> mHolder;
    private Context mContext;

    public ArtistRecyclerView(Context context, List<ArtistHoler> holder) {
        mHolder = holder;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HolderOfArtist onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.resource, parent, false);
        return new HolderOfArtist(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderOfArtist holder, int position) {

        ArtistHoler artistHoler = mHolder.get(position);


        String text1 = artistHoler.getName();





        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .centerCrop()
                .load(artistHoler.getImageUri())
                .into(holder.image);

        holder.image.setOnClickListener(view -> Toast.makeText(mContext, text1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

        holder.name.setText(text1);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mHolder.size();
    }


    public class HolderOfArtist extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView name;

        public HolderOfArtist(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.resource_image);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.resource_text);

        }
    }

}
```

Artist Holders:-

```
public class ArtistHoler {

    private String mName;
    private String mImageUri;

   public ArtistHoler() {
   }

   public ArtistHoler(String name , String imageUri){
       mName = name;
       mImageUri = imageUri;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return mName;
   }

   public void setName(String name){
       mName = name;
   }

   public String getImageUri(){
       return mImageUri;
   }

   public void setImageUri(String imageUri) {
       mImageUri = imageUri;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `click` event on holder item and take the corresponding artist name and pass it to next activity.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderOfArtist holder, int position) {
    ...

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String artistName = mHolder.get(position).getName();
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(mContext, SongsActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra("ArtistName", artistName);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Then in next activity's `onCreate` get the artist name like below and call the firebase to get the songs list of that particular artist and do whatever you want inside `onDataChange`

```
String artistName = getIntent().getStringExtra("ArtistName");

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ArtistSongs").orderByKey().equalTo(artistName).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot song: dataSnapshot.child(artistName).getChildren()) {
             //here song indicates "Song" with SongName and SongUrl
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain, where is the problem?

Comment: Updated `onDataChange` implementation. check now. Hope this will help you. Thanks